# What is PycURL lib?

Tags: python, macos, pycurl

I'm trying to run a program, but it says this:

---

Error importing: pycurl lib.

To install it on Debian based systems:

$ 'sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl'

---

First of all, what is PycURL lib? 
Second of all, is it something you install? If so, how do you?

Just an FYI, I am on Mac

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you format the question with code font?

Answer (score 0):

You can google what pycurl lib is.

As it says there, you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pycurl
```

This needs to be done in terminal on your mac.
Whatever else you were trying to do is dependent upon this.

Comment: Problem is, I don't know the macOS version of "apt-get". I have tried installing PycURL with brew and the easy_install command, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using pip? pip install pycurl or pip3 install pycurl